# Confusing Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

```js
//This is index.php

<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
include 'template_header.php';
include("functions.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>eCommerce template By Adobe Dreamweaver CC</title>
<link href="eCommerceAssets/styles/eCommerceStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#content #text-center nav p {
 font-family: Cambria, Hoefler Text, Liberation Serif, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
}
#content #text-center nav {
 font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, DejaVu Sans, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
</style>

<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/montserrat:n4:default;source-sans-pro:n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">
    <section class="sidebar"> 
      <!-- This adds a sidebar with 1 searchbox,2 menusets, each with 4 links -->
      <input type="text"  id="search" value="search">
      <input type="text" id="search" user_query" placeholder="Search a Product" />
      <div id="menubar">
        <nav class="menu">
          <h2><!-- Title for menuset 1 --> Product Categories </h2>
          <hr>
          <form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Digital">Digital<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Mechanical">Mechanical<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Men">Men<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Women">Women<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Kids">Kids 
</form>
</nav>
        <nav class="menu">
          <h2>Product Brands</h2>
          <!-- Title for menuset 2 -->
          <hr>
          <form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Swatch">Swatch<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Rado">Rado<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Rolex">Rolex<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Citizen">Citizen
</form>
</nav>
<nav class="menu">
          <h2>Product Price</h2>
          <!-- Title for menuset 3 -->
          <hr>
          <form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="BelowRM100">Below RM 100<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="RM101 - RM500">RM100 - RM200<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="RM501 - RM1000">RM501 - RM1000<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="RM1001 - RM1500">RM1001 - RM1500<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="RM1501++">RM1501++
</form>
          
        </nav>
        <div id="form">
     <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     
      
      <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
      
     </form> 
    </div>
      </div>
    </section>
<div>
  <section class='mainContent'> 
        <?php 
   
   
   getPro(); 
   getcatPro();
   getBrandPro();
   
   ?>
            
           
      </section>
      <div>
      <center>
      <style>
ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
}

ul.pagination li a.active {
    background-color:#000000;
    color:black;
}
div.center {
    text-align: center;
}


ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color:#14E318;}
</style>

      <?php 
 
 $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
     $limit = 6; //if you want to dispaly 10 records per page then you have to change here
     $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
        $statement = "products order by product_id asc"; //you have to pass your query over here

  $res=mysql_query("select * from {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
  echo $row["name"];
  echo "<br>";
  }

?>

<?php
echo "<div id='pagingg' >";
echo pagination ($statement,$limit,$page);
echo "</div>";
?>
</center>
</div>
</div>

<?php include 'template_footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>

//This is functions.php

<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");

function getPro(){
  
     global $db;
   
   if(!isset($_GET['type'])){
    
    if(!isset($_GET['brand'])){
 
    $get_products = "select * from products order by rand() LIMIT 0,6";
    
    $run_products = mysqli_query($db, $get_products);
    
    while ($row_products=mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)){
     
     $pro_id = $row_products['product_id'];
     $pro_title = $row_products['product_title'];
     $pro_desc = $row_products['product_desc'];
     $pro_price = $row_products['product_price'];
     $pro_image = $row_products['product_img1'];
      
     echo "
      
        <div id='single_product'>
      
     <h3>$pro_title</h3>
    
     <img src='Images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' /><br>
     
     <p><b>Price: RM $pro_price </b></p>
     
     <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>
     
     <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button style='float:right;'>Add to Cart</button></a>
     
     </div>
     "; 
      
      
        
     
     
     
     
     }
     
 }
   }
     
}

function getcatPro(){
  
     global $db;
   
   if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
    
    $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];
    
    $get_cat_pro = "select * from products where cat_id='$cat_id'";
    
    $run_cat_pro = mysqli_query($db, $get_cat_pro);
    
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_cat_pro);
    
    if($count==0){
     
     echo "<h2>No Products found in this category!</h2>";
     }
    
    while ($row_cat_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_pro)){
     
     $pro_id = $row_cat_pro['product_id'];
     $pro_title = $row_cat_pro['product_title'];
     $pro_desc = $row_cat_pro['product_desc'];
     $pro_price = $row_cat_pro['product_price'];
     $pro_image = $row_cat_pro['product_img1'];
      
     echo "
     <div id='single_product'>
      
     <h3>$pro_title</h3>
    
     <img src='Images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' /><br>
     
     <p><b>Price: RM $pro_price </b></p>
     
     <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>
     
     <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button style='float:right;'>Add to Cart</button></a>
     
     </div>
     ";  
        
     
     
     
     }
     
 
 }
   
}


function getBrandPro(){
  
     global $db;
   
   if(isset($_GET['brand'])){
    
    $brand_id = $_GET['brand'];
    
    $get_brand_pro = "select * from products where brand_id='$brand_id'";
    
    $run_brand_pro = mysqli_query($db, $get_brand_pro);
    
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_brand_pro);
    
    if($count==0){
     
     echo "<h2>No Products found for this brand!!</h2>";
     }
    
    while ($row_brand_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brand_pro)){
     
     $pro_id = $row_brand_pro['product_id'];
     $pro_title = $row_brand_pro['product_title'];
     $pro_desc = $row_brand_pro['product_desc'];
     $pro_price = $row_brand_pro['product_price'];
     $pro_image = $row_brand_pro['product_img1'];
      
     echo "
     <div id='single_product'>
      
     <h3>$pro_title</h3>
    
     <img src='Images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' /><br>
     
     <p><b>Price: RM $pro_price </b></p>
     
     <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>
     
     <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button style='float:right;'>Add to Cart</button></a>
     
     </div>
     "; 
   
        
     
     
     
     }
     
 
 }
   
}
?>
<?php

/**
 * @link: http://www.Awcore.com/dev
 */
 
   function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?'){        
     $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
     $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
     $total = $row['num'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 

     $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
     $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;        
  
     $prev = $page - 1;       
     $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
     $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
     
     $pagination = "";
     if($lastpage > 1)
     { 
      $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                    $pagination .= "<li class='details' style='margin-top:2px'><p>Page $page of $lastpage</p></li>";
      if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
      { 
       for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
       {
        if ($counter == $page)
         $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
        else
         $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";     
       }
      }
      elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
      {
       if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))  
       {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
        {
         if ($counter == $page)
          $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
         else
          $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";     
        }
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";  
       }
       elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
       {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
        {
         if ($counter == $page)
          $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
         else
          $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";     
        }
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";  
       }
       else
       {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
         if ($counter == $page)
          $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
         else
          $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";     
        }
       }
      }
      
      if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
       $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
      }else{
       $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
            }
      $pagination.= "</ul>\n";  
     }
    
    
        return $pagination;
    } 
?>
```

i'm trying to make a simple e-commerce website, I manage to make a pagination, but the function is a bit weird, it works but not in the way it suppose to be. I uploaded 7 products on my website. 1 page can contain 6 products. I want to see it works which is why I insert 7 products. Usually when you click page 2, only product 7 will appear, but in my case, other 5 products from page 1 appear with product 7. I don't know how to solve this, I need help.
Rather than giving screenshot, or copy paste the code here. Here's the link to my project so you can check thoroughly and directly:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/efpt3z33crsckl7/E-commerce.zip?dl=0

If you're kind enough please point out what else I do wrong in my project :D

Edited:

Comment: Copy and paste a code around SQL, you are probably missing OFFSET & LIMIT in your query.

Comment: Please identify the problem area and post the code here. Questions on StackOverflow require a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL has page=2 declaration, if it's page=1 then it won't work for second page.